# Trouble adding icons to KML script

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm having some trouble getting custom icons to display when using KML and google maps. I would like the custom icon that is linked to from the Icon tag to display. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
     <Style id="CaliforniaCity">
        <IconStyle>
         <scale> 1.0</scale>
          <Icon>
            <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/shaded_dot.png</href>
          </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
      </Style>
      <Placemark id=test>
        <name>Test</name>
        <styleUrl>#CaliforniaStyle</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            -121.0,38.0,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark id=test1>
        <name>Test1</name>
        <styleUrl>#CaliforniaStyle</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            -121.05,38.10,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
      </Placemark>
      <Placemark id=test2>
        <name>Test2</name>
        <styleUrl>#CaliforniaStyle</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            -121.10,38.5,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
       </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong as similar code worked in the book.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo CaliforniaCity is not the same as CaliforniaStyle:

```
<Style id="CaliforniaCity">

<styleUrl>#CaliforniaStyle</styleUrl>
```

Your xml is also [invalid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_20140622.kml).

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20140622b.kml)